# Do we need to free the memory of a WCHAR[] assigned to a _variant_t?

Tags: visual-c++, com

```
std::map<int, _variant_t> myMap;

PWCHAR myData= NULL;
//Set myData to some value.

myMap.insert(std::pair<enStoreArchive, _variant_t>(1, myData ));
```

In the above code sample, I have a map which contains a variant pointing to a PWCHAR (bstr).

http://roblocher.com/whitepapers/oletypes.html says that variants will free a BSTR assigned to it, but another line says that values in pointer assigned to _variant_t needs to be manually freed.

Do I need to manally free myData or will _variant_t take care of it?

Comment: You write "pointing to a PWCHAR (bstr)", but `PWCHAR` is not the same as `BSTR`. Their types are compatible, but the semantics are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the destructor of _variant_t, you will see that it calls the windows API VariantClear().

However, the constructor of _variant_t will allocate new data for it.  Therefore, if you use it wrong, you may need to delete myData.  Your current example just shows a NULL pointer.  It's not very helpful at all.

The _variant_t will allocate its own data and really has nothing to do with the memory allocated for myData.  If you allocate memory for myData, you will have to deallocate it--because the _variant_t is going to make its own copy.

Comment: More telling is that the constructor of `_variant_t` says "[_variant_t( wchar_t * wstrSrc  )   Constructs a _variant_t object of type VT_BSTR from a Unicode string. A new BSTR is allocated.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k74e1xsh.aspx)". So the original `wchar_t*` is copied. The variant does not point to `myData`. It points to a copy of `myData`. Therefore, you are responsible for freeing `myData`.

Comment: @RaymondChen We were manually deleting the data allocated by freeing the it.second.bstr, But when the _variant_t itself went out of scope, we got a double free error (when we had appverifier enabled). We now free it.second.bstr and set it.second.vt = VT_EMPTY. This stopped the double free error.

Comment: @GaneshR. But that wasn't your question. Your question is "Do we need to free the `WCHAR[]`?" And the answer is "Yes, because the `_variant_t` made a copy of it." But here you are talking about the `BSTR`, which is a different matter entirely. (Also, you don't need to free `it.second.bstr`; it will be freed when the `_variant_t` is destructed. And even if you choose to free it yourself, make sure you are using `SysFreeString` and not `delete[]`.)

Comment: @RaymondChen In hind sight, yes, I do not need to free it.second.bstr. I will try freeing the PWCHAR after I set the variant and check if it blows up or not and get back here.

Comment: @RaymondChen I changed the code to free the original PWCHAR and let the variant alone. It seems to be working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

VARIANT is an interop type, designed to be useable from different languages that have different runtime implementations.  There is nothing interopable about a WCHAR*, destroying the string buffer cannot be done reliably without the consumer knowing what heap it was allocated on.  Or for that matter if it is even stored on a heap or came from the same process.

So Windows provides a string type that has guaranteed allocate and release semantics, it is `BSTR`.  Underlying winapi calls are SysAllocString() and SysFreeString().  Storage is allocated from a dedicated heap, the one that CoTaskMemAlloc() allocates from.  Also used by SAFEARRAY, another variable length type that requires the same guarantees.

So only way it can work is that your string is *copied*.  Done by the _variant_t constructor that takes a const wchar_t*, it calls SysAllocString().  It is therefore up to you to destroy your string buffer again, you can do so immediately after you assigned it to the variant.  The _variant_t destructor takes care of automatically destroying the copy.

Comment: Agreed. Changed my code to free the PWCHAR and let the variant alone.